# CentOS and 3rd party yum repos (rpmforge/rpmfusion/remi/centalt) and security

Tags: centos, yum, centos6, repository

How safe are these 3rd party yum repos like [rpmforge](http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/)/[rpmfusion](http://rpmfusion.org/)/[remi](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/)/[centalt](http://centos.alt.ru/repository/)/[webtatic](http://repo.webtatic.com/)? Am sure there would be a slight security concern but is there good reason to avoid them completely? Or would doing so be too paranoid?

Has anyone ever had to face any incident due to usage of packages from these repos?